# For loop with set variable but slight change

Tags: matlab, loops

Hi i am wanting to set a for loop that will create a cell array with each element of the cell array is a matrix, however the elements that i want to store in this is x1,x2,x3,x4… is there a way that I could code this such that the ith element of the array is equal to the the ith variable, ie first element of the cell array would be x1, then second would be x2 etc

Comment: Could you provide some examples on what your input and your wanted output look like?

Comment: This is pretty similar to your previous question, if the answer provided to you already wasn't sufficient you should edit your question to clarify the specific issue

Comment: This question is exactly answered in your previous question. If you have a problem with that solution, or need further clarification from the author of that answer, leave a comment under their answer. Stack Overflow is a repository of questions and answers, repeated and duplicated questions make it harder for people to find the answers they need, as answers the one question become spread out over multiple pages rather than all being collected on a single page.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have arrays `x1` through `xi`, which you want to store in cell array 'X', you could use the following for loop:

```
for idx = 1:i
  
  X{idx} = eval(['x' num2str(idx)]);
  
end
```

Here `['x' num2str(idx)]` forms a string containing `x` followed by a number and `eval` evaluates the string as if it was a command.